# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '71.8' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, numeric, varchar

I am trying to convert `varchar(20)` field to `numeric(10,2)` and for this I am using this script:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE Age WHEN 'NULL' THEN 0 ELSE Age END AS numeric(10,2)) AS Age 
FROM   AgeTable
```

But I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '71.8' to data type int.

Comment: What SQL DB are you using? MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, same as [@Mikael Eriksson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9937926), only with more syntactic sugar:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(Age, 'NULL') AS numeric(10, 2)), 0)
FROM AgeTable
```

Comment: it is giving error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: @ARD This works for me. There must be some strange data in the `Age` column. Try `SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM AgeTable` and see if there is anything that isn't "NULL" or a valid number.

Comment: @ARD: Worked for me too. `NULLIF` returns `NULL` if `Age = 'NULL'`, otherwise it return the value of `Age`. The returned result, whether `NULL` or `Age`, is then converted to `numeric(10, 2)`, which is where this query fails for you, I guess. To me, that can mean only one thing: `Age` contains other non-numeric values apart from `'NULL'`. So, as GregL suggests, have a look at the values stored in that column.

Comment: thanks for help.Issue was with the data in the Age field.I found some string and empty values in the Age column.

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement is returning an `int` because of the `then 0` part.

Try this instead:

```
select case Age
         when 'NULL' then cast(0 as numeric(10,2))
         else Age
       end as Age
from AgeTable
```

Comment: Or you could put the cast on the `Age` column in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, try using the `ISNULL()` function instead of your `CASE` statement:

```
Select CAST(ISNULL(Age,0) as numeric(10,2)) as Age 
from AgeTable
```

Comment: This will work assuming OP got this part wrong `when 'NULL'`. It looks like he has `NULL` values stored as the string value `'NULL'`.

Comment: After using above query, it is giving different error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson True. Which is not a great practice, so @ARD, I recommend you store actual null values as `NULL` (not a string), and then my query will work. Is that change possible?

Comment: Actually i am fetching data from production.So changes on production is not possible.